# "Could not read some data from some file"

Tags: warning-messages, error-tracking

This problem happens quite regularly. Does anyone know how to solve it? 
This is the information about the software.

I'm wondering if this is related to Google Drive storage. The file is saved directly on my Google drive on my PC.

[image]

[image]

And I used this to auto save my file as somehow I always lost my file when I forgot to save.

```
saveTask = 
  CreateScheduledTask[FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["Save"]], 1*60];
StartScheduledTask[saveTask];
```

Comment: **I'm wondering if this is related to Google Drive storage.** one way to find out is not to use this drive and see if you still get this or not.

Comment: @Nasser Unfortunately, Google Drive is the cause. I wonder if anyone know how to solve this or know a better online storage service that doesn't have this problem.

Comment: I am frequently working on notebooks stored in Dropbox and sometimes OneDrive, and I have never seen this issue for either location

Comment: @LukasLang I tried OneDrive before and the sync was really bad. I probably switch to Dropbox, it seems to be a bit more expensive than Google Drive.